# mySQL - Copy rows from one database to another with auto increment ids

Tags: mysql

Note: Apologies if this is a duplicate but I can't find a solution.

I have two databases (one dev and one live) which have exactly the same schema.

To make things easier to explain, assume I have a 'customer' table and a 'quote' table. Both tables have auto increment ids and the quote table has a 'customerid' column that serves as a foreign key to the customer table.

My problem is that I have some rows in my dev database that I want to copy to the live database. When I copy the customer rows I can easily get a new id, but how can i get the new id to be assigned to the 'child' quote table rows?

I know I can manually script out INSERTS to overcome the problem but is there an easier way to do this?

EDIT:
This is a simplified example, I have about 15 tables all of which form a hierarchy using auto-increments and foreign keys. There is considerably more data in the live database so the new ids will be bigger (e.g. dev.customer.id = 4, live.customer.id = 54)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually managed to do this (as per my comment) but in order to do so I had to write some code. In the end I created some dummy tables that kept track of the old id against new id so. When copying over records with FK constraints I just looked up the new id based on the old. A bit long winded but it worked.

This post is getting on a bit now so I've marked this as the answer. If anyone out there has better ideas/solutions that work I'll happily 'unmark' it as the accepted answer.

EDIT: As requested here is some pseudo-code that I hope explains how I did it.

I have the two related tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tblCustomers (
  Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  Address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM
ROW_FORMAT = fixed;

CREATE TABLE tblQuotes (
  Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CustomerId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  QuoteReference varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM
ROW_FORMAT = fixed;
```

I create an extra table that I will use to track old ids against new ids

```
CREATE TABLE tblLookupId (
  Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TableName varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  OldId int DEFAULT NULL,
  NewId int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM
ROW_FORMAT = fixed;
```

The idea is that I copy the tblCustomer rows one at a time and track the ids as I go, like this:

```
// copy each customer row from dev to live and track each old and new id
//
foreach (customer in tblCustomers)
{
    // track the old id
    var oldid = customer.id; // e.g. 1

    // insert the new record into the target database   
    INSERT newdb.tblCustomers (...) VALUES (...);

    // get the new id
    var newid = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() // e.g. 245

    // insert the old id and the new id in the id lookup table
    INSERT idlookup (TableName, OldId, NewId) VALUES ('tblCustomers', oldid, newid); // this maps 1->245 for tblCustomers
}
```

When I come to copy the table (tblQuote) with the foreign key I have to first lookup the new id based on the old.

```
// copy each quote row from dev to live and lookup the foreign key (customer) from the lookup table
//
foreach(quote in tblQuotes)
{
    // get the old foreign key value
    var oldcustomerid = quote.CustomerId; // e.g 1

    // lookup the new value
    var newcustomerid = SELECT newid FROM tblIdLookup WHERE TableName='tblCustomers' AND oldid=oldcustomerid; // returns 245

    // insert the quote record
    INSERT tblQuotes (CustomerId, ...) VALUES (newcustomerid, ...);
}
```

I've tried to keep this short and to the point (and language agnostic) so the technique can be seen. In my real scenario I had around 15 'cascading' tables so I had to track the new ids of every table not just tblCustomer

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you did to solve this? I know it's been a while -- but this is a great question, and a full-fledged answer would be great.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang I've added some pseudo-code that I hope explains this technique. I've done this quite a few times now, it's not quick and not pretty but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 25):

Easiest way without changing any IDs.

1. Ensure that you are currently in the table where the record you want to copy is in (source db).
2. Run the following command:

```sql
INSERT INTO to_database.to_table 
  SELECT * FROM from_table WHERE some_id = 123;
```

No need to specify columns if there is no need to remap anything.

Hope that helps!

Comment: that is fine for a single table, but I have a hierarchy of tables with FK constraints. As I stated, I know it can be manually scripted.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I have since overcome this by creating  interim tables without auto increments but GUIDs instead and then mapping tables to provide a lookup to the 'old' Id of each record in each table.

Comment: Helpful yes, but needs a correction: We'll need to be on the from_database (`use from_database`) when we run this query, but within the query itself it should say `from_table` where it says `from_database`.

Comment: This also works in one database when you are copying data from one schema to another, i.e. INSERT INTO schema1.tableName SELECT * FROM schema2.tableName WHERE x=y;

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT` ... `SELECT`:

```
insert into your_table (c1, c2, ...)
select c1, c2, ...
from your_table
```

where *c1, c2, ...* are all the columns except `id`.

Comment: This will work for the first table (customer) but what about the second (quote)?

Comment: probably a nested query in quote, fetching the correct id of customer

Comment: Thanks, sounds like we're going in the right direction. Any chance you could provide an example?